# How to save regular expression objects in a dictionary?

Tags: python, regex

For a first-semester task I'm supposed to write a script that finds first and last names in a file and displays them in the following order (last name, first name) next to the original entry (first name, last name).

The file has one entry per line which looks as follows: "Srđa Slobodan ĐINIC POPOVIC".

My questions are probably basic but I'm stuck:

1. How can I save all the entries of the file in a hash (multi-part first names/multi-part lastnames)? With `re.compile()` and `re.search()` I only manage to get one result. With `re.findall()` I get all, but can't `group.()` them and get encoding errors.
2. How can I connect the original name entry (last name/first name) to the new entry (first name/last name).

   ```
   import re, codecs

   file = codecs.open('FILE.tsv', encoding='utf-8')
   test = file.read()
   list0 = test.rstrip()

   for word in list0:
        p = re.compile('(([A-Z]+\s\-?)+)')
        u = re.compile('((\(?[A-Z][a-z]+\)?\s?-?\.?)+)')

        hash1 = {}
        hash1[p.search(test).group()] = u.search(test).group()

        hash2 = {}
        hash2[u.search(test).group()] = p.search(test).group()

   print hash1,'\t',hash2
   ```

Comment: Why not make a dictionary with empty strings for their value and the original list as the key? Then you could just iterate over the keys of the dictionary with a foreach, so replacing the empty value with the transformed string from the key should be pretty easy to track.

Comment: Dictionary keys must be a hashable type. The objects you trying to use as a key are likely not hashable and thus you can't use them as keys.